# How to find the total amount of characters in w string?

Tags: java, string, character, counting

I'm trying to find out the total chars within an inputted string. When I input the string (a sentence), it is only counting the total number of characters within the first word of the string. I need it to count the total amount of characters. I understand that there are many ways to doing this. But this is for my intro course and the only method I can use it a string.length(); method.

This is what I have:

```
String shortSentence;
System.out.println("Please input a short sentence, with a period at the end.");
shortSentence = keyboardReader.next();
String length = shortSentence.length(); 
System.out.println("The total characters in the sentence is " + length);
```

Comment: And string.length() gives you the total amount of characters....

Comment: Use nextLine instead of next

Comment: no, when I enter a string for shortSentence, like "hey there.", it is only reading a total of 3 characters for the "hey" within the string, I need it to count the total amount of characters within the ENTIRE string. So it should be a total of 10 characters, including the space

Comment: As I said, you are using next() and it fetches the characters until it encounters space, use nextLine() to grab the whole line. So instead of `shortSentence = keyboardReader.next();` do `shortSentence = keyboardReader.nextLine();`

Comment: Sorry, posted the comment before yours was posted. In which it worked! Thank you so much. Pretty much all Im going off of are the slides from my class lecture, in which the example doesn't show the nextLine(), just next(). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use `nextLine()`

```
shortSentence = keyboardReader.nextLine();
```

Convert the length to string:

```
String length = Integer.toString(shortSentence.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.println("Please input a short sentence, with a period at the end.");
    InputStreamReader r=new InputStreamReader(System.in);  
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(r);   
    String shortSentence=br.readLine();  

    System.out.println(shortSentence.length());

}
```

}

This gives me output as 11 for input as 'hello world'. See if this helps.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you would explain what the original code was doing wrong.